# Perform $group and count in mongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, sum, aggregation

Given that I have a complex grouping requirement, I was wondering what would be the best approach to achieving my desired result.
My data (result of $project stage) would look something like this:

```
{
_id:$id
status:"available"
inspectionStatus:"done"
state:"completed"
category:"One"
},
{
_id:$id
status:"booked"
inspectionStatus:"none"
state:"active"
category:"Two"
},
.
.
.
```

I have tried using `$facet` to create multiple buckets since the grouping I am trying to create are aggregations of `$status` + `$state` + `$inspection`, but the execution time is way unacceptable, taking something around `1639763842` milliseconds.
I can't use use `$accumulator` because of mongoDB version (although we can always upgrade to 4.4.x) but I am not sure whether using `$accumulator` would produce a better response time.

The `$facet` stage is included:

```
{
  "available": [
    {"$match": 
      {$and: [
        {"status": "available"},
        {"inspectionStatus": "done"}
      ]}
    }
  ],
  "matched": [
    {"$match": 
      {$and: [
        {"status": "booked"},
        {"state": "booked"}
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "inIntake": [ 
    {"$match": 
      {$and: [
        {"status": "available"},
        {"inspectionStatus": {$ne: "done"}}
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "active": [
    {"$match": 
      {$and: [
        {"status": "booked"},
        {"state": "active"}
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "unreturned":[
    {"$match": 
      {"status": "forceCompleted"}
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are you saying you wish to `{$group: {_id: {status:"$status",state:"$state",inspection:"$inspection}, n: {$sum:1} }}` ?   This will count all combos of status / state / inspection.

Comment: well not really... I don't need all the combinations, I need a sub-set of the combinations as `unreturned`, `active`,  `inIntake`, `active`, and `available`

Comment: I suspect you don't need `$facet` here because you're not using the engine to group anything, only filtering.   If the subset in total represents a large percentage of the total collection size, don't even bother using `$match`:  just do ` simple `find()` and use client side logic to pick out `unreturned`, `active`, etc.  If not, use a single `$match` with a big `$or` expression for the facets above -- and you will still have to use client side logic to segregate the results.

Comment: Also:  How many docs are we talking about here?  1639763842 millis is almost 19 *days*.

Comment: sorry copied the wrong value. It should have said `11333` mils. for `79188` records.

Comment: I think that `$facet` is unnecessary.  I loaded 80000 docs like yours into a collection and did a `find()` with no filter to get *all* docs *and* fetch them (but not print them) and that took between 630 and 700 millis on a MacBookPro 2.7G quadcore 16GB RAM.   What percentage of your 80000 docs do you expect to satisfy one of your 5 conditions?

Comment: The count of the collection is `79203` records.

Comment: I meant out of the `79203`, how many fall into one of your 5 categories?   Do you expect *all* docs to fit into one of those categories?

Comment: the total document count 80,000, and 79203 fall within one of the 5 categories.

Comment: OK, so there is little value in having the database do any work except vend the content.   Just do `find()` and let the client side code do the logic.   You will throw away <1% of the material and the DB will run as fast as it possibly can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to push the logic to the DB, here's a solution -- but you still have to examine the `XX` field doc by doc:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
    {$addFields: {XX: {$switch: {
    branches: [
            { case: {
        $and: [{$eq:["$status","available"]},{$eq:["$inspectionStatus","done"]}]
            }, then:'AVAILABLE' },
            { case: {
        $and: [{$eq:["$status","booked"]},{$eq:["$state","booked"]}]
            }, then:'MATCHED' },
            { case: {
        $and: [{$eq:["$status","available"]},{$ne:["$inspectionStatus","done"]}]
            }, then:'IN_INTAKE' },
            { case: {
        $and: [{$eq:["$status","booked"]},{$eq:["$state","active"]}]
            }, then:'ACTIVE' },
            { case: {
        $eq:["$status","forceCompleted"]
            }, then:'UNRETURNED' },
    ],
        default: null
    }}
                 }}
    ,{$match: {XX: {$ne: null}}}
]);
```

The end-to-end timing on this is actually a bunch of millis better than simple `find()` because less material is transferred but of course the DB engine is working a little harder processing the pipeline.